# How can I use placeholder in a Django template translation using the lazy syntax?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-i18n

The documentation is unclear on this matter. As per the [Chapter 19: Internationalization › In Template Code](https://django-book.readthedocs.org/en/latest/chapter19.html#in-template-code) section, it is possible to use syntax such as:

```
{% some_special_tag _("Page not found") value|yesno:_("yes,no") %}
```

However, I want to pass a placeholder to pass a variable to the translation as in :

def my_view(request, m, d):
    output = _('Today is %(month)s %(day)s.') % {'month': m, 'day': d}
    return HttpResponse(output)

### Attempts

I tried the following syntaxes:

```
{% back_link 'core:work_unit' _('Unité de travail #%(id)') % {'id': requested_work_unit.id} %}
```

Give :

> TemplateSyntaxError at /unit/109/edit/
>
> Could not parse the remainder: '%' from '%'

And this one

```
{% back_link 'core:work_unit' _('Unité de travail #%(id)', requested_work_unit.id) %}
```

Give:

> StopIteration at /unit/109/edit/
>
> No exception message supplied

### Question

How can I use the lazy notation and placeholder in template tag ?

Comment: This ticket might help [Allow blocktrans to set a context variable](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21695)

Answer (score -1):

If I've got you right, you can put variables within [blocktrans](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#std:templatetag-blocktrans) tag:

```
<p>{% blocktrans with user.email as email %}Please confirm that <a href="mailto:{{ email }}">{{ email }}</a>.{% endblocktrans %}</p>
```

And in your translation file:

```
#: templates/account/email_confirm.html:17
#, python-format
msgid ""
"Please confirm that <a href=\"mailto:%(email)s\">%(email)s</a>"
msgstr ""
"Пожалуйста подтвередите <a href=\"mailto:%(email)s\">%(email)s</a>"
```

In [custom tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) you can do what ever you want:

```
@register.simpletag
def not_found(case):
    if case:
        return _("Page not found")
    return _("Yeah!")
```

Comment: I'm aware of the `blocktrans` and the `_()`/lazy notation in python code. What I'm looking for is how to use lazy notation in a template context as an argument to a custom tag